# What is the name of this plant with a compound leaf of 8 leaflets?

Tags: botany

this plant is present in my lawn and I don't know it's name. It is actually diseased and I'm trying to figure out what it is.
[image]

Comment: Can you please add some geographic location of your garden? Also information if this plant is native there or just planted would be helpful.

Comment: Is this related? https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/30373/what-disease-is-causing-raised-blisters-on-the-leaves-of-my-plant

Answer (score 0):

I think it's [ https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rauvolfia_caffra ] Still not sure, but it's worth giving a try... :)